# How applied a multiple textures images or one image into a cube in qt 6 with qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6, qt3d

Hello I am learning Qt 3d in version 6.4.2 using QTCreator and **qml** and after researching in the official qt documentation and even here in stack overflow I did not find a way to put several images as faces of a cube or one texture image mapped in, I tried using CubeMapTexture but I get an error, I also tried with the material but I couldn't either

here is a minimal code to reproduce

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick3D
import QtQuick3D.Effects
import QtQuick3D.Helpers
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    id: window
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    visible: true
    title: "Example"
    color: "#848895"

    SplitView {
        id: splitView
        anchors.fill: parent

        View3D {
            id: viewport
            SplitView.fillHeight: true
            SplitView.fillWidth: true
            SplitView.minimumWidth: splitView.width * 0.5
            environment: SceneEnvironment {
                property bool enableEffects: false
                antialiasingMode: SceneEnvironment.MSAA
                antialiasingQuality: SceneEnvironment.High
                lightProbe: Texture {
                    source: "maps/OpenfootageNET_garage-1024.hdr"
                }
                effects: enableEffects ? [bloom, scurveTonemap] : []
                backgroundMode: SceneEnvironment.SkyBox

                SCurveTonemap {
                    id: scurveTonemap
                }
                HDRBloomTonemap {
                    id: bloom
                }
            }

            Node {
                id: originNode
                PerspectiveCamera {
                    id: cameraNode
                    z: 600
                    clipNear: 1
                    clipFar: 10000
                }
            }

            PrincipledMaterial {
                id: basicMaterial
                baseColorMap: CubeMapTexture{
                    source: "maps/side.png"
                }
            }

            Model {
                id: cube
                source: "#Cube"
                materials: basicMaterial
                pickable: true
            }


            OrbitCameraController {
                origin: originNode
                camera: cameraNode
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: pickController
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: function(mouse) {
                    let pickResult = viewport.pick(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                    if (pickResult.objectHit) {
                        let pickedObject = pickResult.objectHit;
                        // Move the camera orbit origin to be the clicked object
                        originNode.position = pickedObject.position
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The error using CubeMapTexture is this "Sampler qt_BaseColorMap_sampler expects a 2D texture but the associated texture is a cube map. This will lead to problems."
but in other ways I can't put multiple textures in the cube or just one texture and map it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Texture` consider using `sourceItem`. That will allow you to use traditional 2D components such as `Image` as your texture. In my example, I've used SVG images so that I can quickly apply a mixture of vector graphics to my textures. For you, you don't have to limit yourself to using `Image` as your `sourceItem`. You can choose, any 2D component, e.g. `Item`, `Rectangle`, `Text`, `Label`, `Canvas`, `Shape`, etc.

```
      materials: [
           DefaultMaterial {
                diffuseMap: Texture {
                    sourceItem: Image {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        width: 224
                        height: 224
                        source: "Dice1.svg"
                        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
                        cache: false
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

If you use "#Cube", the Material(s) you use will be the same on all 6 sides. If you switch to using 6 "#Rectangle"s, you can use a different material for each rectangle. We can use this technique to create a 6-sided dice. Each face of the dice is rendered with its own SVG image:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick3D
Page {
    id: page
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    header: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "#eee" }
        CheckBox { id: chkLabels; text: qsTr("Labels"); checked: true }
    }
    Node {
        id: standAloneScene
        DirectionalLight { ambientColor: Qt.rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) }
        Node {
            id: node
            Repeater3D {
                model: [
                    ["Dice1.svg", 0, 0 ],
                    ["Dice6.svg", 0, 180 ],
                    ["Dice3.svg", 0, 90 ],
                    ["Dice4.svg", 0, -90 ],
                    ["Dice2.svg", 90, 0 ],
                    ["Dice5.svg", -90, 0 ],
                ]
                delegate: Node {
                    eulerRotation.x: modelData[1]
                    eulerRotation.y: modelData[2]
                    Model {
                        source: "#Rectangle"
                        materials: [
                            DefaultMaterial {
                                diffuseMap: Texture {
                                    sourceItem: Item {
                                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                                        width: 224
                                        height: 224
                                        Image {
                                            anchors.fill: parent
                                            source: modelData[0]
                                            sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
                                            cache: false
                                        }
                                        Label {
                                            visible: chkLabels.checked
                                            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                                            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                                            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
                                            text: modelData[0]
                                            color: "white"
                                            Rectangle {
                                                anchors.fill: parent
                                                anchors.margins: -5
                                                color: "blue"
                                                border.color: "yellow"
                                                radius: 5
                                                z: -2
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                        z: 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        OrthographicCamera {
            id: cameraOrthographicFront
            lookAtNode: node
            y: 800; z: 1000
            property double sc: 300/Math.max(Math.min(page.width, page.height), 1)
            scale: Qt.vector3d(sc, sc, 1)
        }
    }
    View3D {
        anchors.fill: parent
        importScene: standAloneScene
        camera: cameraOrthographicFront
    }
    NumberAnimation {
        target: node
        property: "eulerRotation.y"
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        from: 720; to: 0
        duration: 10000
    }
    NumberAnimation {
        target: node
        property: "eulerRotation.x"
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        from: 360; to: 0
        duration: 10000
    }
}

// Dice1.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<rect width="32" height="32" fill="#444"/>
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="4" fill="#800"/>
</svg>

// Dice2.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<rect width="32" height="32" fill="#444"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="8" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="24" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
</svg>

// Dice3.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<rect width="32" height="32" fill="#444"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="8" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="24" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
</svg>

// Dice4.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<rect width="32" height="32" fill="#444"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="3" fill="#800"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="8" r="3" fill="#800"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="24" r="3" fill="#800"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="24" r="3" fill="#800"/>
</svg>

// Dice5.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<rect width="32" height="32" fill="#444"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="8" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="24" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="24" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
</svg>

// Dice6.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<rect width="32" height="32" fill="#444"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="16" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="8" cy="24" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="8" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="16" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
<circle cx="24" cy="24" r="3" fill="#ccc"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)